# Postgresql "column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" and unique field

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, inner-join, aggregate-functions

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL,
    content text
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    email character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying NOT NULL
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_users_on_email ON users USING btree (email);
```

The following SQL request:

```
SELECT posts.content, users.email /*, other aggregate fields not relevant for the question */
   FROM posts
   INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
   GROUP BY posts.id;
```

gives the error `column "users.email" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

But the email field is unique (if it changes anything) and a post can only have one user (so one email).

Why is this request not valid, since it's not possible to have multiple values of `email` per `post`?

Comment: The bigger question is why you are using `GROUP BY` in the first place when you never select any aggregate functions.  Maybe you can describe what you want your query to do here.

Comment: A given post's content might have more than one user email associated with it.  Keep in mind that even if the relationship really happens to be one-to-one, Postgres does not know this.

Comment: I'm not sure why. `users.id` is also unique so I can't think of a way where a post can have more than one user. I see this error in different requests for several years now, so I'm a bit frustrated to not understand it correctly :D

Comment: This is the point: Even though it might be one to one, Postgres doesn't know this.  For reference, your query would run without error (and with a correct expected result set) on MySQL with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode turned off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the primary key of the user table to the `group by` clause to make the query a valid aggregation query:

```
SELECT p.content, u.email /*, other aggregate fields not relevant for the question */
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id
/* Other `inner join`s but not relevant for the question */
GROUP BY posts.id, u.id;
```

Postgres is quite smart about functional dependencies, but not *that smart*. It understands the concept of functionally-dependent columns, but not *across* tables so it cannot foresee that a `post` uniquely refers to a user, even if you have a proper foreign key set up. I don't think that such thing is defined in standard ANSI SQL either.